# C# - SQL Server connection string not working in a new version of SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have downloaded, for educational purposes a restaurant C# application which uses SQL Server 2012 as a backend database. I am using SQL Server 2016.

The connection string in the code is:

```
Data Source=SONY\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=cindyDB;Integrated Security=True
```

I tried to changed it to match the location, but nothing seems to work and it doesn't read data from the `.mdf` file. I also added a ADO.NET Data Entity Model to import the `.mdf` file but it doesn't work.

Can you help me with what should I change in the C# code and how to change the `.mdf` from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2016?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. Are you saying that the downloaded sample contained an .mdf file (and presumably an .ldf file, since you need both to make a database)?  You need to ATTACH the mdf/ldf files to a running SQL Server instance before accessing them. You can't just go directly do them and do anything.

Comment: @pmbAustin You don't need an ldf file to attach a database.

Comment: The connection string in the projects connects to a database **on the server** (where it belongs - SQL Server **is** a server-based solution - not a file-based one). So you need to install SQL Server Express (if you haven't already), and then you need to create the `CindyDB` database **on the server** (using e.g. SQL Server Management Studio) and then your app can connect to that **server-based database** (and you let the server / DBA handle all the details of having one or multiple `.mdf` and/or `.ndf` files .....)

Comment: Also you computer name is probably not SONY.

Comment: I am not that a beginner. That's what I need to change, the connection string, but I tried everything I found on the web but still doesn't work. I was hopping you will have an example.                                              But why can't I attach the .mdf file to SQL Server 2016, it gives me the following error: Unable to open the physical file "D:\Database1.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5120)

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnbZT.png)

You can add connection from Server Explorer then provide your localhost IP and test connection then the property you will find the connection string.